# Retrofit 2.0.2: how to cache GET request?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to do caching of my get request. For retrofit 2 It is seeming I dont have to use OKHttp for this. How can I cache then? I am trying like this:

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL /*+ API*/)
            .cache(new Cache(App.sApp.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    if (ApiUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
                    } else {
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).build();
                    }
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()));
```

But it is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found **`OkClientFactory`** from [Retrofit2](https://github.com/GDGAhmedabad/Learning-Resources/tree/master/android/examples_demos/Retrofit%202.0) Demo in **GDGAhmedabad Repo**

Maybe it will helps you.

```
public class OkClientFactory {
    // Cache size for the OkHttpClient

    private static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50MB

    private OkClientFactory() {
    }

    @NonNull
    public static OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Application app) {
        // Install an HTTP cache in the application cache directory.
        File cacheDir = new File(app.getCacheDir(), "http");
        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.interceptors().add(loggingInterceptor);
        }
        return builder.build();
    } }
```

Now you can use like:

```
.client(App.getInstance().getOkHttpClient())
```

See [here](https://github.com/GDGAhmedabad/Learning-Resources/blob/master/android/examples_demos/Retrofit%202.0/RetrofitDemoBasic/app/src/main/java/com/retrofitdemo/api/ApiFactory.java#L9) for more

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to cache only GET requests.

```
public class CachingControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
    if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
        if (ConnectivityUtil.checkConnectivity(getContext())) {
            // 1 day
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                .build();
        } else {
            // 4 weeks stale
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                .build();
        }
    }

    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600")
        .build();
}
}
```